# Removing range of items from a list

Tags: python, list, filtering

Is there a way to remove items in a range in list? For example: `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`. How to remove items from *3* to *5*?

Comment: yes, but first consider posting a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your gui

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because it filters on a criterion rather than the last *n* elements.

Comment: Reopened; the dupe and target are sufficiently different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
[z for z in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] if not 3<=z<=5]


Out[2]:
[1, 2, 6, 7]
```

If you want to make it more flexible can replace with variables depending on your needs which is simply done:

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
lowerbound=3
upperbound=5
resultlist=[z for z in alist if not lowerbound<=z<=upperbound]
#result you want stored as 'resultlist'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a list comprehension to filter the data.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print([x for x in a if 3 <= x <= 5])
```